# Is $y'''-3e^ty''- y'=t$ is a liner differential equation or a nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: calculus

Is $y'''-3e^ty''- y'=t$ a linear differential equation or a nonlinear differential equation?

I know the distinction between a linear D.E and nonlinear D.E but I am confused about this particular equation since the y term is missing. I know that if a D.E is of degree 2 and with y term is missing then it can be converted into a linear D.E but what is with this equation?

Comment: What would adding $0 \cdot y$ change about this equation?

Comment: If we add 0.y then then equation becomes linear. Are you suggesting that?

Comment: It is a (non homogeneous) linear differential equation with non-constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's linear, just with non constant coefficients. If fact the coefficient of $y$ term is $0$. Also by $v=y'$ you can reduce it's degree to $2$.